# Adding Javascript in Homepage.ascx in DotNetNuke

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I just want to add a small Javascript in DNN homepage.ascx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//jkmegamenu.definemenu("anchorid", "menuid", "mouseover|click")
jkmegamenu.definemenu("megaanchor", "megamenu1", "mouseover")

</script>
```

Please Experts help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy Phillip
You must insert your script in Page Settings - Advanced Settings - Page Header Tags textbox or change .ascx file in .\portals_default\skins\DarkKnight\<>.ascx

Regards.
Claudio Venturoli
DotNetNuke.it staff